# CSS Sticky Footers with Unknown Height

Tags: css, sticky-footer

Is there any way to stick a footer to the bottom of the browser screen or right after the content (depending on which is longer) using CSS *without* knowing the size of the footer in advance?

Right now I am using the absolute positioning in a container that holds the footer and the content with container's min-height as 100%, but if I change the footer I find I must change the padding at the bottom of the container to match its height.

Comment: Is this what you want? 1. a region that contains the page content (I will call this "the content"). 2. a region following "the content" that is the footer. 3. If the "the content" gets long, the footer is pushed of the page but will show up if the user scrolls the page.

Comment: @dwb: yes, but the bottom of the footer is always at least on the bottom of the window, and we don't necessarily know the height of it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

**Summary:**

For a site with a header, content area, and footer:

1. Set `html, body {height: 100%;}`
2. Set your body (or a wrapper div) to `display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;`
3. Set your header, footer, and content area to `display: table-row;`. Give your header and footer `height: 1px;`, and give your content area `height: auto;`

   The header and footer will both expand to fit their content. The content area will expand to fit the larger of its content, or the available space.

https://jsfiddle.net/0cx30dqf/

Comment: a solution like this is exactly what I was looking for at the time, I've bookmarked it for when I'll inevitably need it in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know why this was accepted as the answer, when it clearly says you need the height of the footer in the how-to... >.>

Comment: @BrianGraham, no it doesn't. "Most of them (e.g. CSSStickyFooter) require a fixed height footer [...] however, here is an easy and plain CSS solution for sticky footers with fluid height"

Look in the code samples too, it doesn't need the height of the footer anywhere in there.

Comment: Please provide a summary and not just a link. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You should add `table-layout: fixed;` to the wrapper div. Without that I had some width issues in IE. The content was overflowing regardless of the maximum width.

Comment: Is there a reason why any `border` setting disappears when I turn on the `display: table-row;` property?

Comment: @Brian Graham, `table-cell` doesn't lock the height like block would have, instead, it allows the field to expand; therefore the height is unknown.

Comment: @HelpNeeder I ended up using this solution back then, I just forgot to reply to this thread. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 24):

If you're willing to jump into the HTML5 future, you can use **flexbox**...

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
   flex: 1;
}
```

- My more detailed answer to the same question: [How to make a fluid sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901707/how-to-make-a-fluid-sticky-footer/20432414#20432414) (full example: http://jsfiddle.net/n5BaR/)
- Solved by flexbox: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/
- What is Flexbox from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: This has major issues with safari and IE <=11.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige - The caveat "If you're willing to jump into the HTML5 future" is an important qualifier. IE11 has some bugs with its flexbox support, and I wouldn't recommend it for sites that have significant users in IE < 11. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Luke I'm not denying that. I still think it is interesting for users to know, that there are issues with browsers, which are considered to support fexbox (partly true for ie 10/11, true for safari >9).

Comment: Update: Currently IE 11 makes up ~4% of traffic (http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-market-share), and all other browsers (desktop and mobile) fully support flexbox. https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

Uses Flex!

**NO FIXED HEIGHT, JAVASCRIPT OR TABLES**

Expands when more content, and when there isn't it sticks to bottom

**Note:** Does not work with IE 9 & Below

```css
*{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%; 
}
body{
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.content{
  flex: 1;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <div class='content'>
    This is the page content
    <br>
    PS. Don't forget the margin: 0 and padding: 0 to avoid scrollbars (this can be also put into the   body css)
  </div>
  
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Because people have to support legacy browsers like Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Dodekeract IE 11 and 10 have support, IE 9 and below are barely used nowadays

Comment: @dude Worked with mine, try going into the developer tools and make sure you're using the IE 11 document mode.

Comment: It doesn't work once the main content goes beyond footer... in that case footer doesn't remain sticky and goes below the fold

Comment: That's not a sticky footer then, that's a fixed footer @kushdilip

Comment: @Albert This is great! Very clean solution.

Comment: @Dodekeract IE is more legacy than browser. It is a pure disgrace and there is not event the slight justification for the use of that monstrosity in the 21st century.

Answer (score 1):

For an app with a responsive footer (i.e. changes height on resize), you can use jquery to dynamically adjust the padding of the bottom for the parent element. Adding onto this post: [Keep Footer at Bottom](https://medium.com/@zerox/keep-that-damn-footer-at-the-bottom-c7a921cb9551)

HTML:

```
<div class=”main-container”>
   <header>
    this is a header
   </header>
   <section>
    this is content
   </section>
   <footer>
    this is a footer
   </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.main-container {
 min-height: 100vh; /* will cover the 100% of viewport */
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 100px; /* height of your footer */
}
footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

CoffeeScript:

```
footerEventListener = ->
  $(window).on "resize", ->
    setFooterHeight()

setFooterHeight = ->
  // get footer height in px
  bottomPadding = $("footer").css("height")
  $(".main-wrapper").css("padding-bottom", "#{bottomPadding}") 

// init footer events
setFooterHeight()
footerEventListener()
```

Check out the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeff71jeff/pen/RzMpxY?editors=0000) here.

Answer (score 0):

since no one knows the answer for sticky footer w/o knowing the height of it, using css (crosbrowser solution), i was forced to calculate it

jquery:

```
if( $(document).height() < $(window).height() )
{
    $('#content').height
    (
        $(window).height - $('#footer').height()
    );
}
```

html structure:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is just add a class to your footer. Javascript will do the rest.

```js
//This Pen is By Mohammad Abdus Salam
//portfolio.codeexposer.com
    var footerHeight = $('footer.fixed_footer').height();
    if($('footer').hasClass('fixed_footer')){
        $( "section" ).last().css({
            "margin-bottom": footerHeight + 'px'
        });
    }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800');
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
}
section{
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 9;
}
h1{
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
  width: 700px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.logo{
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer_top{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.logo img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer_bottom {}
.footer_bottom p{
  color:#aaa;
}
.footer_top{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.footer_bottom p a{
  color:#158;
}
footer{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #222222;
}
.fixed_footer{
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is Banner</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugiat amet explicabo illum, soluta quisquam minus consectetur totam omnis non veniam possimus atque nisi earum aperiam quasi ut, quas temporibus minima eius, rem repellat. Sed eius quae eum qui odio molestiae porro. Aut ab impedit recusandae odit at? Quas ab laboriosam culpa, rerum nobis consequatur voluptate nemo expedita voluptatem porro aliquid dolorum maiores autem dolorem unde mollitia quae nam fugit. At quibusdam error consequatur suscipit? Necessitatibus asperiores, doloribus accusamus odit quidem deserunt cum reiciendis aliquid ipsam alias distinctio recusandae earum nam nulla ratione quia architecto beatae nihil expedita blanditiis animi sit, exercitationem tempora placeat. Accusamus ad odio natus, pariatur sed tenetur debitis. Soluta distinctio velit beatae asperiores eligendi? Neque quasi doloremque cumque placeat ea sapiente recusandae harum veritatis corrupti! Ad, alias, at cum debitis sit obcaecati vitae nesciunt aliquam nulla laudantium ut sunt veniam distinctio mollitia sed neque qui sint repudiandae adipisci deserunt perspiciatis consectetur optio blanditiis? Unde distinctio dolorum laboriosam dolorem ex in, porro facilis ad velit beatae excepturi ut aspernatur! At sunt tempora, placeat veritatis excepturi hic repellendus pariatur dolores deserunt cupiditate exercitationem laborum itaque sapiente nostrum non, quibusdam explicabo velit dolorum cum. Maiores, accusamus! Iusto, rem doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is About</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugiat amet explicabo illum, soluta quisquam minus consectetur totam omnis non veniam possimus atque nisi earum aperiam quasi ut, quas temporibus minima eius, rem repellat. Sed eius quae eum qui odio molestiae porro. Aut ab impedit recusandae odit at? Quas ab laboriosam culpa, rerum nobis consequatur voluptate nemo expedita voluptatem porro aliquid dolorum maiores autem dolorem unde mollitia quae nam fugit. At quibusdam error consequatur suscipit? Necessitatibus asperiores, doloribus accusamus odit quidem deserunt cum reiciendis aliquid ipsam alias distinctio recusandae earum nam nulla ratione quia architecto beatae nihil expedita blanditiis animi sit, exercitationem tempora placeat. Accusamus ad odio natus, pariatur sed tenetur debitis. Soluta distinctio velit beatae asperiores eligendi? Neque quasi doloremque cumque placeat ea sapiente recusandae harum veritatis corrupti! Ad, alias, at cum debitis sit obcaecati vitae nesciunt aliquam nulla laudantium ut sunt veniam distinctio mollitia sed neque qui sint repudiandae adipisci deserunt perspiciatis consectetur optio blanditiis? Unde distinctio dolorum laboriosam dolorem ex in, porro facilis ad velit beatae excepturi ut aspernatur! At sunt tempora, placeat veritatis excepturi hic repellendus pariatur dolores deserunt cupiditate exercitationem laborum itaque sapiente nostrum non, quibusdam explicabo velit dolorum cum. Maiores, accusamus! Iusto, rem doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is Service</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugiat amet explicabo illum, soluta quisquam minus consectetur totam omnis non veniam possimus atque nisi earum aperiam quasi ut, quas temporibus minima eius, rem repellat. Sed eius quae eum qui odio molestiae porro. Aut ab impedit recusandae odit at? Quas ab laboriosam culpa, rerum nobis consequatur voluptate nemo expedita voluptatem porro aliquid dolorum maiores autem dolorem unde mollitia quae nam fugit. At quibusdam error consequatur suscipit? Necessitatibus asperiores, doloribus accusamus odit quidem deserunt cum reiciendis aliquid ipsam alias distinctio recusandae earum nam nulla ratione quia architecto beatae nihil expedita blanditiis animi sit, exercitationem tempora placeat. Accusamus ad odio natus, pariatur sed tenetur debitis. Soluta distinctio velit beatae asperiores eligendi? Neque quasi doloremque cumque placeat ea sapiente recusandae harum veritatis corrupti! Ad, alias, at cum debitis sit obcaecati vitae nesciunt aliquam nulla laudantium ut sunt veniam distinctio mollitia sed neque qui sint repudiandae adipisci deserunt perspiciatis consectetur optio blanditiis? Unde distinctio dolorum laboriosam dolorem ex in, porro facilis ad velit beatae excepturi ut aspernatur! At sunt tempora, placeat veritatis excepturi hic repellendus pariatur dolores deserunt cupiditate exercitationem laborum itaque sapiente nostrum non, quibusdam explicabo velit dolorum cum. Maiores, accusamus! Iusto, rem doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is Portfolio</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugiat amet explicabo illum, soluta quisquam minus consectetur totam omnis non veniam possimus atque nisi earum aperiam quasi ut, quas temporibus minima eius, rem repellat. Sed eius quae eum qui odio molestiae porro. Aut ab impedit recusandae odit at? Quas ab laboriosam culpa, rerum nobis consequatur voluptate nemo expedita voluptatem porro aliquid dolorum maiores autem dolorem unde mollitia quae nam fugit. At quibusdam error consequatur suscipit? Necessitatibus asperiores, doloribus accusamus odit quidem deserunt cum reiciendis aliquid ipsam alias distinctio recusandae earum nam nulla ratione quia architecto beatae nihil expedita blanditiis animi sit, exercitationem tempora placeat. Accusamus ad odio natus, pariatur sed tenetur debitis. Soluta distinctio velit beatae asperiores eligendi? Neque quasi doloremque cumque placeat ea sapiente recusandae harum veritatis corrupti! Ad, alias, at cum debitis sit obcaecati vitae nesciunt aliquam nulla laudantium ut sunt veniam distinctio mollitia sed neque qui sint repudiandae adipisci deserunt perspiciatis consectetur optio blanditiis? Unde distinctio dolorum laboriosam dolorem ex in, porro facilis ad velit beatae excepturi ut aspernatur! At sunt tempora, placeat veritatis excepturi hic repellendus pariatur dolores deserunt cupiditate exercitationem laborum itaque sapiente nostrum non, quibusdam explicabo velit dolorum cum. Maiores, accusamus! Iusto, rem doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is Banner</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta fugiat amet explicabo illum, soluta quisquam minus consectetur totam omnis non veniam possimus atque nisi earum aperiam quasi ut, quas temporibus minima eius, rem repellat. Sed eius quae eum qui odio molestiae porro. Aut ab impedit recusandae odit at? Quas ab laboriosam culpa, rerum nobis consequatur voluptate nemo expedita voluptatem porro aliquid dolorum maiores autem dolorem unde mollitia quae nam fugit. At quibusdam error consequatur suscipit? Necessitatibus asperiores, doloribus accusamus odit quidem deserunt cum reiciendis aliquid ipsam alias distinctio recusandae earum nam nulla ratione quia architecto beatae nihil expedita blanditiis animi sit, exercitationem tempora placeat. Accusamus ad odio natus, pariatur sed tenetur debitis. Soluta distinctio velit beatae asperiores eligendi? Neque quasi doloremque cumque placeat ea sapiente recusandae harum veritatis corrupti! Ad, alias, at cum debitis sit obcaecati vitae nesciunt aliquam nulla laudantium ut sunt veniam distinctio mollitia sed neque qui sint repudiandae adipisci deserunt perspiciatis consectetur optio blanditiis? Unde distinctio dolorum laboriosam dolorem ex in, porro facilis ad velit beatae excepturi ut aspernatur! At sunt tempora, placeat veritatis excepturi hic repellendus pariatur dolores deserunt cupiditate exercitationem laborum itaque sapiente nostrum non, quibusdam explicabo velit dolorum cum. Maiores, accusamus! Iusto, rem doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<footer class="fixed_footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer_top">
        <a class="logo" href="portfolio.codeexposer.com">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-a700z77yIxk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/RzvY_qm9KQY/s512-p/photo.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_bottom">
      <p>
        All Rights Reserved By <a href="http://portfolio.codeexposer.com">Mohammad Abdus Salam</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -2):

<del>Take a look at this, [cssstickyfooter](https://example.com), it works great in any browser.</del>

**Update**: This is from 2010, might not be relevant with current standards

Comment: I looked at this; this is a good solution if you know the height of the footer in advance.