# Fluid sticky footer with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make footer at the bootom with flex as described in this question [How to make a fluid sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901707/how-to-make-a-fluid-sticky-footer/20432414#20432414)

the answer with adding to the body

```
body {
     padding: 0; margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     min-height: 100vh;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

and main

```
main {
     flex: 1;
     padding: 1em;
}
```

works fine if header, main and footer is one after another and all is inside body

but what if header is outside like in this template

```
<body>
   <div id="headerDiv"> This is header </div>
   <div id="mainDiv"> 
       <div id="contentDiv"> This is content </div>
       <div id="footerDiv"> This is footer </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

then if I add body class to `body` html element and main class to `contentDiv` it does not work
if I add body class to `mainDiv` and main class to `contentDiv` then it almost works but my footer is lower of height of the `headerDiv` and there is scroll, how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if ?

the second container can be a flexbox too ,

Use the same CSS flex technic applied to `body` and `#mainDiv` to `#mainDiv` and `#contentDiv`, minus height since `flex:1;` is already sizing `#mainDiv`.

```css
body,
#mainDiv  {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#mainDiv,
#contentDiv {
  flex: 1;
}

/* see them */
#headerDiv,#footerDiv {background:yellow;padding:1em}
#mainDiv {background:pink;}
```

```html
<div id="headerDiv"> This is header </div>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="contentDiv"> This is content </div>
  <div id="footerDiv"> This is footer </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a flex container on the `#mainDiv` with `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
}

#mainDiv {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headerDiv"> This is header </div>
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="contentDiv"> This is content </div>
    <div id="footerDiv"> This is footer </div>
  </div>
</body>
```