# Sticky Footer (with unknown Height) with pur CSS3 using HTML5 for all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer

I am trying to implement a STICKY FOOTER **(with unknown Height)** for my website in HTML5 and CSS3. I have tried so many ways, but there seems to be a problem with the `margin` of my main part.

Here is what I have:

```css
 body {
   background: #000;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
 main {
   margin: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <div id="first">
  </div>

  <main id="main">
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

The HEADER and FOOTER are equal to the body - so, no more code.

*Please note: I have used the **reset.css** to do everything on my own!*

Here is what I tried the last hours:

- [CSS Sticky Footers with Unknown Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347133/css-sticky-footers-with-unknown-height)
- http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/
- http://blog.mojotech.com/responsive-dynamic-height-sticky-footers/
- http://timothy-long.com/responsive-sticky-footer/
- https://gist.github.com/jdlich/4166622
- http://www.ninjabuilt.com/36/simple-sticky-footer/
- http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/DCmtI
- AND MUCH MORE...

Please do not recommend the FLEXBOX - that does not work on mobile devices and in the IE 10.

Comment: Flexbox works in IE 10 with the `-ms` prefixes...

Comment: Okay, but what about my smartphone and tablet? The Safari on my iPhone does not support the FLEXBOX. :/

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/de/verwendung.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Footer with a Height, that I do not know. I have edited that.

Comment: FLEXBOX does not work in IE 10 by just using the -ms- prefixes... just tried. :/

Comment: @Exception Flexbox works in IE 10 with `-ms-` prefixes, are you sure you prefixed the correct properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an example for you using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/ed4xe1z9/

HTML

```
   <div id="wrap">
        <header>
            <p>The header</p>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="the-margin">
                <div id="first">
                     <h1>First Content</h1>

                </div>
                 <h2>Main Content</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Sticky footer</p>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
        * {
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background: #000;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #main {    
            overflow:auto;
        }
        .the-margin{
            margin: 50px;
        }
        footer {
            position: relative;
            clear:both;
        }
```

jQuery on document ready

```
$('#main').css('padding-bottom', $('footer').height());
$('footer').css('margin-top', -$('footer').height());
```

Comment: Didn't saw that you want it in pure css :) Just saw the unknown height of the footer :)

Comment: No problem, Bojan! ;) That solved my problem. JS was not the way I wanted to solve it, but it works - so, who cares. ;)

Comment: Oh just one thing: Which jQuery do you think I should pick for my script? The latest one `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` makes the website very slow...

Comment: You need to load a minified version of jQuery, and I always use the one provided from google 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay, thank you. And why don't you use the one from jQuery? I mean, you do not buy a Porsche at the BMW Store - you go to a Porsche Store, don't you? :P

Comment: Just a habit I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried one thing for sticky footer , i am adding its html and css3 code.

I am also giving the reference site.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

The body content should be inside the wrap.

css

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

I referred the following website for the sticky footer

```
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that it works, but I need a Footer where its Height is not known.

Comment: Then what should the height be

Comment: 100% (regarding to its Content) ;)