# Stickyfooter with dynamic height

Tags: css

I am trying to recreate the answer to this question: [CSS Sticky Footers with Unknown Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347133/css-sticky-footers-with-unknown-height)

So basically i want a sticky footer which has the ability to change it's height (dynamic). So I do not know the height.

Here is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/ZQXJdQ?editors=110

i can't seem to get it to work.

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
    roger<br>
  </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  display: table-row;
  height: auto;
}
.div2 {
  display: table-row;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the other answers to the question? If I understood correctly, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/g22x195z/

Comment: @FaustoNA I must of misunderstood the term "sticky". Afaiak sticky means that the footer will always show all the time?

Comment: Oh! I think I can do that. Sorry I understood you incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:** http://jsfiddle.net/3sLa37dv/

*I'm sorry I completely misunderstood your first request, hope this fixes it.*

I used a small jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#content').css('margin-bottom', $('#footer').height() + 'px');
});
```

It adds `margin-bottom:;` to the `#content` by the height of the `#footer`. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed however the issue here is that some of the "hello" text is hidden under the footer now :(

Comment: Updating the answer. Now I'm pretty sure I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use flexbox instead of tables.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper .div1 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

See flexboxfroggy.com to learn more about flexbox.